# for loop with arithmetic expression

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can I use arithmetic expressions in a for loop?

e.g.

```
<script>
   var i=2;

   for(i=2;i<10;i+2){
      document.write(i);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: You shouldn't be declaring the variable that you are using for the loop.  Unless you need to use it elsewhere once the loop is done.

Comment: Yes you can. But `i+2` by itself will compute `i+2` and discard the results (the value of `i` won't change). Perhaps you mean `i += 2`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not adding `2` to `i`, but that `i+2` is not an assignment, so it will result in an infinite loop. You can write it like this:

```
var i;
for(i = 2; i < 10; i += 2){
  document.write(i);
}
```

`i += 2` means "add 2 to `i` and store the result in `i`", basically twice `i++`.

Example fixed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rmuyyjaz/).

Example with infinite loop [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rmuyyjaz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

With [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment):

> The addition assignment operator adds the value of the right operand to a variable and assigns the result to the variable. The types of the two operands determine the behavior of the addition assignment operator. Addition or concatenation is possible. See the [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) for more details.

```
for (i = 2; i < 10; i += 2) {
//                    ^^
```

Example:

```js
var i =0;
for (i = 2; i < 10; i += 2) {
    document.write(i + '<br>');
}
```